# Reading the excel cell validation dropdown value in C# using openXML

Tags: c#, excel, drop-down-menu, console-application, openxml

I am writing a C# console application that will read values from an excel spreadsheet using OpenXML and create a DataTable. The app is able to read all values except those cells which contain a dropdown list. Is there a way for OpenXML to read these cells and determine which value is selected? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Current Code:

```
public static string GetValue(Cell cell, SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart)
    {

        if (cell.ChildElements.Count == 0) return null;

        //get cell value

        string value = cell.ElementAt(0).InnerText;//CellValue.InnerText;

        //Look up real value from shared string table

        if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))

            value = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;

        return value;

    }

    public static void ReadData(string xlsxFilePath, string sheetName)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsxFilePath, true))        
        {

            //Access the main Workbook part, which contains data
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))            
            {
                Sheet ss = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).SingleOrDefault<Sheet>();
                worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(ss.Id);
            }            
            else            
            {
                worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
            } 

            SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;

            if (worksheetPart != null)            
            {
                Row lastRow = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().LastOrDefault();
                IEnumerable<Row> firstRows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().Skip(10);
                Row firstRow = firstRows.FirstOrDefault();
                int numColumns = 0;
                //Row firstRow = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstRow != null)                
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in firstRow.ChildElements)                    
                    {
                        string value = GetValue(c, stringTablePart);
                        dt.Columns.Add(value);
                        numColumns++;
                    }
                }

                if (lastRow != null)                
                {
                    for (int i = 11; i <= lastRow.RowIndex; i++)                    
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        bool empty = true;
                        Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>() .Where(r => i == r.RowIndex).FirstOrDefault();

                        int j = 0;
                        if (row != null)                        
                        {
                            foreach (Cell c in row.ChildElements)                            
                        {
                            //Get cell value
                            string value = GetValue(c, stringTablePart);
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value == " ")
                                dr[j] = "";
                            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value != " ")
                            //    empty = false;
                            else
                                dr[j] = value;
                            Console.Write(dr[j] + "\t");
                            j++;
                            if (j == numColumns-1)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\n");
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        //if (empty)
                        //    break;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```